# jar related to hadoop-2.7.3 is not found in lib folder

Tags: hadoop

I downloaded Hadoop 2.7.3 version now I want all jar related to this version but inside lib folder of this version not showing any jar.Previously when I was working on hadoop-1.2.1 inside lib folder of it I got all the jar.So from where could I get all jar related to Hadoop -2.7.3
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In Hadoop 2.x, the jar location has changed from `${HADOOP_HOME}/lib` to `${HADOOP_HOME}/share/hadoop/common/lib`

All the jars can be found at:

```
${HADOOP_HOME}/share/hadoop/common       
${HADOOP_HOME}/share/hadoop/common/lib   
${HADOOP_HOME}/share/hadoop/mapreduce    
${HADOOP_HOME}/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib
${HADOOP_HOME}/share/hadoop/yarn         
${HADOOP_HOME}/share/hadoop/yarn/lib
```

---

You might also want to take a look at : [Migrating fro Hadoop MRv1 to MRv2](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-3-x/topics/cdh_ig_mapreduce_to_yarn_migrate.html)